# Working out a team's rolling form for its previous six games

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with lots of football scores. I have attached it so you know what I'm talking about.

Here is one of the entries:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
| Ref | Output | Home      | Away      | HTHome | HTAway |    Date    | FTHome | FTAway | HT | FT | HT | FT | Away | HT | Away | FT | Away | HT | FT |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
|  1  |    1   | Arsenal   | Leicester |    2   |    2   | 11/08/2017 |    4   |    3   |  D |  W | DW |  D |   L  | DL |      |    |      |    |    |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
```

From this, I know that Arsenal won the game 4-3.

The spreadsheet contains lots of rows like this. What I would like to do, is work out a team's previous form before its next game.

For example, on Boxing Day, Liverpool played Swansea:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
| Ref | Output | Home      | Away      | HTHome | HTAway |    Date    | FTHome | FTAway | HT | FT | HT | FT | Away | HT | Away | FT | Away | HT | FT |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
| 194 |   20   | Liverpool | Swansea   |    1   |    0   | 26/12/2017 |    5   |    0   |  W |  W | WW |  L |   L  | LL |      |    |      |    |    |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+----+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+----+----+
```

Liverpool's form for its previous six games, would be `W W D D W D`. I will eventually be converting this information into a single number, e.g. with `3` for a Win, `1` for a Draw, and `0` for a Loss, Liverpool would have a "score" of `12`.

The games can be either Home and Away, and I would like to know the form of the previous six games regardless of where they were played. I also wish to be able to drag the formula down, so that I can enter next weeks fixtures and have the previous form generate correctly.

I have seen lots of other solutions for a form table. My requirements are different as I would like to know the previous form for each match throughout the season.

It would also be handy if the formulas could easily be adapted to check the form of, say, the last 3 games.

Prem.xlsx

Any questions, please let me know.

---

Here is the link to the data:

http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/E0.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two example entries don't match the data in the linked CSV file and are a bit unclear. It seems like you are importing the CSV file into a workbook and modifying it. (You forgot to paste the link to the workbook, though.)

Thus, for my solution I'm going to use the unmodified CSV file data. You will have to adjust the formulas to suit your actual table. Also, since the "score" of the relevant previous six games is actually simpler to calculate than the individual win/loss/draw results, my formula will return that:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `BN2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down&right/auto-fill into the rest of the table's `BN` and `BO` columns:

```dart
=IFERROR(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(+($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="H")+1*($G$1:$G1="D"))+($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="A")+1*($G$1:$G1="D")),{6,5,4,3,2,1})),100),0)
```

---

**Explanation:**

The prettified version of the formula is as follows:

```dart
=
IFERROR(
  MOD(
    SUMPRODUCT(
      LARGE(
        +($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="H")+1*($G$1:$G1="D"))
        +($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="A")+1*($G$1:$G1="D")),
        {6,5,4,3,2,1}
      )
    ),
    100
  ),
  0
)
```

For each previous row containing the target team, the formula creates a special value. (For other rows the value is zero.) The rightmost two digits of the special value contain the outcome value (`3` for a win, `1` for a draw, and `0` for a loss) whilst the leftmost digits contain the row number.

The `LARGE()` function then selects the most recent six matching rows' special values (i.e. the ones with the largest six row numbers in the leftmost digits). Using `SUMPRODUCT()` on these six values results in a single value where the rightmost two digits are the sum of the outcome values, i.e. the "score". The `MOD()` function extracts this score.

The `IFERROR()` function is there to remove the `#NUM!` error that occurs in row `2` to row `6` (due to `LARGE()` trying to get the largest six values of an array containing less than six elements).

Note that if there are less than six previous matches for the target team, the value of the elements of the array corresponding to the missing matches will be zero.

Stepping through the formula in `BO22` should make the above clearer. Note that since `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted to `1` and `0` respectively when used in a multiplication, for compactness reasons I will be using those numbers in the following evaluations.

- `100*ROW($G$1:$G21)+3*($G$1:$G21="H")+1*($G$1:$G21="D")`
  → `100*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21}+3*({0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;0;1;0;0})+1*({0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1})`
  → `{100;203;300;400;500;603;701;801;903;1003;1100;1200;1300;1403;1503;1603;1703;1800;1903;2000;2101}`, the special values for the home teams for all the previous rows
- `($C$1:$C21=D22)*({100;203;300;400;500;603;701;801;903;1003;1100;1200;1300;1403;1503;1603;1703;1800;1903;2000;2101})`
  → `({0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1})*({100;203;300;400;500;603;701;801;903;1003;1100;1200;1300;1403;1503;1603;1703;1800;1903;2000;2101})`
  → `{0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2101}`, the special values if the home team matches the target team (`D22`) for all the previous rows
- Similarly, `($D$1:$D21=D22)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G21)+3*($G$1:$G21="A")+1*($G$1:$G21="D"))`
  → `{0;0;303;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`, the special values if the *away* team matches the target team for all the previous rows
- `+{0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2101}+{0;0;303;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
  → `{0;0;303;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2101}`, the special values if a match involved the target team for all the previous rows. (Note that, as the two arrays are "mutually exclusive", summing them will not cause any interference.)
- `LARGE({0;0;303;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2101},{6,5,4,3,2,1})`
  → `{0,0,0,0,303,2101}`, the special values of the previous six matches involving the target team
- `SUMPRODUCT({0,0,0,0,303,2101})`
  → `2404`, where the rightmost two digits are the "score", i.e. the sum of the outcome values, and the irrelevant leftmost digits are the sum of the row numbers. (Note that `SUMPRODUCT()` is used instead of `SUM()` so the inner sub-expressions are evaluated as arrays, thus avoiding the need to array-enter the formula.)
- `MOD(2404,100)`
  → `4`, the "score" (or form) of the previous six matches involving the target team

---

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- You will need to retain the `FTR` column (`G:G`) from the raw CSV file for the formulas to work. (The column is not strictly required, but the formulas need to be adjusted to work without it. I chose to use the column as it makes the formula easier to read.)
- Modifying the formula to only use the previous three relevant games is a simple matter of changing `{6,5,4,3,2,1}` to `{3,2,1}`.
- The row scaling factor is only guaranteed to work if `[# relevant previous games]*[max outcome value] < [row scaling factor]`. Using the example's values, `6*3=18 < 100`, so we can see that `100` is the minimum scaling factor that will work. (Well, actually the minimum *power of ten* scaling factor, as `19` is the *absolute* minimum.)
- <s>If you actually require the individual outcomes of the relevant previous six matches, I can add that to the answer.</s> Added.

---

#### Addendum #1:

For the individual outcomes of the current row's home team's previous six matches, multi-cell array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in six consecutive cells of row `2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the table's columns (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=
CHOOSE(1+
  IFERROR(
    MOD(
      LARGE(
        +($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="H")+2*($G$1:$G1="A")+1*($G$1:$G1="D"))
        +($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)+3*($G$1:$G1="A")+2*($G$1:$G1="H")+1*($G$1:$G1="D")),
        {6,5,4,3,2,1}
      ),
      100
    ),
    0
  ),
  "-","D","L","W"
)}
```

For the individual outcomes of the current row's *away* team's previous six matches, just change both `=C2` for `=D2`.

To return the outcomes as a string in a single cell, just wrap the whole formula with `TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,…)`. (Only works natively in Excel 2016. Earlier versions of Excel require a poly-fill UDF - see [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)

**Explanation:**

The formula is basically the same as the previous one with just three modifications:

1. An outcome value of `2` is added for a loss
2. The outcome values are no longer summed
3. Instead, they are used as the first argument (i.e., as indexes) of the `CHOOSE()` function to select the appropriate outcome characters.

---

Finally, just to show you I wasn't kidding about the score being easier to calculate than the individual outcomes, the following is the simplest outcomes formula which doesn't first calculate the individual score values:

```dart
{=
IF(
  ISERROR(0/LARGE(ROW($G$1:$G1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1})),
  "-",
IF(
  "D"=INDEX($G:$G,N(IF(1,1+LARGE((ROW($G$1:$G1)-1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1})))),
  "D",
IF(
  +("H"=INDEX($G:$G,N(IF(1,1+LARGE((ROW($G$1:$G1)-1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1})))))
  *(C2=INDEX($C:$C,N(IF(1,1+LARGE((ROW($G$1:$G1)-1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1})))))
  +("A"=INDEX($G:$G,N(IF(1,1+LARGE((ROW($G$1:$G1)-1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1})))))
  *(C2=INDEX($D:$D,N(IF(1,1+LARGE((ROW($G$1:$G1)-1)*(($C$1:$C1=C2)+($D$1:$D1=C2)),{6,5,4,3,2,1}))))),
  "W",
"L"
)))}
```

---

#### Addendum #2:

All the previous formulas take advantage of the fact that the headers for columns `C`, `D`, and `G` don't match any of the data values in those columns, and that the values in the columns are only used in comparisons. This means that the value of the first element (i.e. corresponding to the header row) of the arrays for the home and away teams will be a zero.

However, if the values in the columns are actually used numerically in the formula, as in the case when getting the total of the goals scored by each team in their last six matches,

```dart
=
IFERROR(
  MOD(
    SUMPRODUCT(
      LARGE(
        +($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($E$1:$E1)+$E$1:$E1)
        +($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($F$1:$F1)+$F$1:$F1),
        {6,5,4,3,2,1}
      )
    ),
    100
  ),
  0
)
```

then the value of the first element of the arrays will be the error value `#VALUE!`, the `LARGE()` function will always return the array `{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`, and the formula will always return a zero.

There's a couple of ways to solve this.

One way is to enter the formula starting from row `3` instead of row `2` and changing it so that the ranges start from row `2` instead of row `1` (e.g. `$C$2:$C2=C3` instead of `$C$1:$C2=C3`). The values for row `2` will always be zeroes, of course, and can be manually entered as such.

Another way is to wrap the sum of the arrays in an `IFERROR()` function to convert the error in the first element to a zero before passing it to the `LARGE()` function:

```dart
{=
IFERROR(
  MOD(
    SUMPRODUCT(
      LARGE(
        IFERROR(
          +($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($E$1:$E1)+$E$1:$E1)
          +($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($F$1:$F1)+$F$1:$F1),
          0
        ),
        {6,5,4,3,2,1}
      )
    ),
    100
  ),
  0
)}
```

**Notes:**

- This formula needs to be array-entered. Normally, expressions within a `SUMPRODUCT()` function are evaluated as arrays, but expressions inside a nested `IFERROR()` are one of the exceptions.
- Since the formula is array-entered, `SUM()` can be used instead of `SUMPRODUCT()`. (Remember, it was only originally used to force array evaluation *without* requiring the formula to be array-entered.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect, if you could include this "If you actually require the individual outcomes of the relevant previous six matches, I can add that to the answer." that would be perfect. I can't believe how good of an answer you have given, I am extremely grateful!!!!!!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Okie, dokie. Added the individual outcomes formulas.

Comment: You're the best

Comment: Hi @robinCTS can you think of an easy way to get the goals scored by each team in the last 6,3 games. I have tried to convert your formula but I'm struggling a little bit.

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Just replace the home team outcome values, `+3*($G$1:$G1="H")+1*($G$1:$G1="D")`, with the home team goals `+$E$1:$E1`. Similarly replace the away team outcome values, `+3*($G$1:$G1="A")+1*($G$1:$G1="D")`, with the away team goals `+$F$1:$F1`. (Using the first formula, of course.)

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar No problems. (If you really appreciated my help, once you reach 15+ reputation don't forget to come back and upvote my answer as well ;-) )

Comment: I 100% will! Do you do any paid work, I am only a student but I work part-time for a company that uses excel and I would definitely recommend you!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar I do. Provided it's either in Western Australia, or telework ;-)

Comment: I meant online, in a similar method to answering questions like this :)

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Yes. I thought that's what teleworking meant in a broader sense. I probably should have been explicit about purely online ;-)

Comment: I am using this formula for the goals and it doesnt seem to work, =IFERROR(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(+($C$1:$C1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)++$E$1:$E1)+($D$1:$D1=C2)*(100*ROW($G$1:$G1)++$F$1:$F1),{6,5,4,3,2,1})),100),0)   ... can you see anything obviosuly wrong. Thanks so much again!!!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Sorry. I didn't test the goals solution I proposed in my previous comment - for the first element of the arrays generated, it attempts to add the header value (which isn't a number, obviously) to the scaled row number, and the resulting error causes the entire formula to evaluate as zero. I've added a couple of ways to solve this to my answer. (I'm assuming that your `++` are just attempts to coerce to a number, or typos. In either case, they have no effect on the formula.)